# Script won't run within WordPress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I'm developing a very simple plugin that calculates a total of fields based on user input.

The plugin displays a form that calls an associated javascript. I began by creating one file (script + html form) which runs fine in my local WP div site, but when I "split it" into the script file and the html file, the form will not calculate within WP. I verified the script is running on the page, but the form does not calculate.

Here's a snippet of the script:

```
<script language="Javascript"><!--
function addUp(form) {
var LR_bookcaseV;
LR_bookcaseV =parseInt(document.spacecalc1.LR_bookcase.value);
if (isNaN(LR_bookcaseV) || LR_bookcaseV == "") {
    LR_bookcaseV = 0;
}

var APP_aircondV;
APP_aircondV =parseInt(document.spacecalc1.APP_aircond.value);
if (isNaN(APP_aircondV) || APP_aircondV == "") {
APP_aircondV = 0;
}
-->
```

Here's a snippet of the form:

```
<form name="spacecalc1">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" frame width="100%" height="850">
<tr> 
<td width="107" valign="bottom" style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1"> 
<div class="maintext"> <font size="1" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif">       
<b>Living Room</b></font></div></td>
```

The JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p8j3T/2/

It doesn't like jsfiddle but, again, this will run on a page as ONE file, with the script preceeding the form, within WordPress.

Help appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You probably copy the script tags from the javascript when you use the script in an external file. Remove those and you're good. I've updated the fiddle so it works to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/p8j3T/3/

remove:

```
<script language="Javascript"><!--
```

and

```
// -->
        </script>
```

---EDIT---

answers for the comments below:

A: (this one will make sure jquery is loaded also)

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script(
    'default',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/default.js',
    array( 'jquery' )
); ?>
```

B:

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/your-js-file.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great idea! But still the script won't run. The script shows in the html generated page, but no functionality. I've spent a lot of time on this and I'm stuck!

Comment: Make sure you either use the wordpress way to embed javascript (A) or use the bloginfo method to get the full url for the js file inside your template (B). Due to lack of formatting in this comment I'll put A and B in the answer above..

Comment: And use a debugger to see if you don't have any js errors, such as firebug or Chrome developer tools (cmd-option-J) or IE developer tools (F12)

Comment: Okay, thanks, I think my issue may be within the plugin's php functions. I think I have the script enqueued the "WP way."
I need to do three things:
1. Load the script.
2. Retrieve a form that will go on a post or page via
3. A shortcode.
Thus far, I am loading the script, loading the form, calling the form via the shortcode, but the form and script are not functioning together. I'm not quite sure how to approach the issue!

Comment: Check for javascript errors with the browsers debugging options (firebug, dev.tools, ...). You'll propably see what's wrong quickly. Is your site online where I can see it?

Comment: It's on my Xampp dev site. I could zip it and put it live somewhere... Here's the core of the plugin file:

/* Register script*/
wp_register_script( 'NDM-mini-storage-calculator', plugins_url('/NDM-mini-storage-calc/NDM-mini-storage-calculator.js', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'NDM-mini-storage-calculator' );

/* Add function and shortcode */
function show_calc_form(){
    return $options = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( plugins_url() . '/NDM-mini-storage-calc/mini-storage-calculator_noscript.html' ) );
}
add_shortcode('NDM-mini-calc', 'show_calc_form');

Comment: Moved discussion to here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23132447/my-first-wordpress-plugin-cant-get-script-to-run