# My first WordPress plugin - Can't get script to run

Tags: javascript, php, forms, wordpress

I thought this would be really simple but have spent a few days and am stuck.

The idea is to insert a form on a page via shortcode; the form calculates totals from user input. The script and form play fine together when placed in a single HTML file. In the plugin (as you will see), the JS and FORM file are called separately. Currently, the script loads in the output, the form loads on the page that has the shortcode, but the CALC function will not work, either locally or on my server. Here are the bare-bones functions from my plugin:

```
/* Register and enqueue the script*/
wp_register_script( 'ndm-mini-storage-calculator', plugins_url('/ndm-mini-storage-calc/ndm-mini-storage-calculator.js', __FILE__ ) );
wp_enqueue_script( 'ndm-mini-storage-calculator' );


/* Add function to load the form and add shortcode */
function show_calc_form(){
return $options = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( plugins_url() . '/ndm-mini-storage-calc/mini-storage-calculator_noscript.html' ) );
}
add_shortcode('ndm-mini-calc', 'show_calc_form');
```

Script and form is here: http://jsfiddle.net/p8j3T/2/

Live page is here: http://www.northwindcomputing.com/ndm-mini-storage-calc-test/

Thanks!!

Comment: [How to load JavaScript like a WordPress Master](http://scribu.net/wordpress/optimal-script-loading.html)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the plugin URL, `plugins_url` will get that for you.
It's also a good idea to load files on init

```
add_action('init', 'load_ndm_mini');

function load_ndm_mini(){
    wp_register_script( 'ndm-mini-storage-calculator', plugins_url('ndm-mini-storage-calculator.js', __FILE__ ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ndm-mini-storage-calculator' );
}
```

If you open the console, you'll notice the url looks like

http://www.northwindcomputing.com/wp-content/plugins/ndm-mini-storage-calc/ndm-mini-storage-calc/ndm-mini-storage-calculator.js?ver=3.9

While the script is located at

http://www.northwindcomputing.com/wp-content/plugins/ndm-mini-storage-calc/ndm-mini-storage-calculator.js?ver=3.9

the plugin path is added twice.

Comment: Doing so breaks it; activating the plugin returns error, etc.

Comment: On 'activate' (on local server) returns: 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in E:\Websites\www.newdestinytest1.dev\wp-content\plugins\NDM-mini-storage-calc\ndm-mini-storage-calc.php on line 34'

Maybe it's "register" and "enqueue"? I think you are correct, I'm just not seeing the fix!

Comment: There's a typo somewhere, you have an unexpected comma. It's really hard to see where when I don't have anything to test, but read the error message thouroughly, find the line with the error, and read that until you figure out where it is.

Comment: Oh, a little late there! great, happy to help

Comment: Ooops, only works on local server... still working on it! (At least it's working there!) Issues now is, the HTML page will not load via shortcode.

Comment: You do have the same issue in the shortcode handler, where you use both plugins_url *and* the URL to the plugin, adding it twice. It does seem strange that the shortcode would work locally and not on a live server?

Comment: I am updating / rewriting the files correctly. I don't think it's a server catching issue... I guess it's time I learn the Java console!